# OPENDIR the value from $_REQUEST

Tags: php, opendir

anybody can help to solve this problem. i have 2 files php :

1. file list folder which send `$_REQUEST` as Link
   example : http://localhost/sertifikat/bacafolder.php?Link=%20Cipto%2075%20HGB%201159%20207%20M2
2. file php for execute and OPENDIR that $Link. 
   but its can't work, even though that Folder is exist

this is the second file php :

```
<?php   
$Link=$_REQUEST['Link'];
$dir= $Link;

echo $dir;

if($opendir=opendir($dir))
    {while(($file=readdir($opendir)) !=FALSE)
        {
        echo "<img src='$dir/$file'><br>";
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: What is your error message?

Comment: There is a space in front of `Cipto`. Your filenames probably don't start with a space. Also add code to restrict what files the user can open. You don't want to get hacked.

Comment: @Adder - you mean directory transversal attacks?  I was thinking the same thing.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix: Well yes that is what I mean. Except here isn't any protection existing even that could be bypassed by directory traversal.

Comment: Yea if `$file` was a PHP file, that could be bad. It would execute through the image link.